# Getting 0 Month with Current Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

Here is my code:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(sp.timestamp);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

When I do this,

`Log.d("month", String.valueOf(month));`

I get 0.

I also Logged the `sp.timestamp` and it is `1410460389`.  I am expecting to return "8" (as it is September).  There are only three lines and they look correct so I am completely at a loss with this?

Comment: What's `sp.timestamp`?

Comment: It's a timestamp and I logged it as shown above, the value is 1410460389.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1410460389` is in seconds while `setTimeInMillis` requires milliseconds.

Therefore, try:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(sp.timestamp * 1000L);
```

Comment: That is right.  Horrible mistake.  Thanks... marking correct when time allows.

Answer (score 1):

`1410460389` corresponds to January 17, 1970. The first month starts with a zero.

The current timestamp should be `1410469839296` which shows your timestamp is actually in seconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: Weird.  I supplied the timestamp here, http://www.epochconverter.com/ and got the correct time?

Comment: You're getting the timestamp probably in seconds instead of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Month is 0-based, that's why it's zero. Here's Calendar's javadoc about it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH